# Ubuntu partition disappeared after laptop ran out of battery

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, battery

I've been unable to boot on the ubuntu 20.04 partition after my laptop shut down because it ran out of battery.

After I plugged the PC again, it booted straight into the Windows partition installed on the same NVME drive and I realised my UEFI parameters were resetted, and date and time were not correct any more. I suspect the BIOS battery, which I changed last year, might be dead again.

I changed the boot options again and got to the GRUB screen, chose "Ubuntu" and the booting process hangs as shown below:
[Boot hangs there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln8S5.jpg)

I did try to use the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and what I think are previous versions of the kernel and their recovery modes, with no luck.

Would you have an idea to help me get my OS back? It's my second Linux install and I worked hard to get everything working!

**UPDATE 1:** When starting with a liveusb, blkid and fdisk -l don't even show the disk on which the OSes are installed:
[blkid and fdisk -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl737.png)

However, I can see and select both OSes in the BIOS/UEFI, and can boot on the Windows partition, which should imply there's no problem with the hard drive itself:
[UEFI HDD boot option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh08n.jpg)

**UPDATE 2:**
Running blkid from BusyBox after booting fails doesn't show the sdd where the OSes are installed either...
[blkid in BusyBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkTpj.jpg)

**UPDATE 3:**
The partition on which Ubuntu is (was?) installed is visible in Windows Disk Management tool: [It is the 270.45GB partition on disk 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ILP.png)

The question is, why isn't it found by the bootloader?

**UPDATE 4:**
I've just tried installing testdisk on the liveusb session and, again, the SDD with the OSes is not shown.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

The "SATA Mode Selection" option in the UEFI was reset to "RAID". Selecting "AHCI" allowed Ubuntu to boot.

Thank you @kanehekili for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem one week ago. Start your laptop with a live usb stick, open terminal and enter

`fsck /dev/sdX -y`

where sdX should be the system harddisk. If not sure, check it with `blkid`, all commands with **sudo**

**Update**

your blkid says:

> /dev/sda ntfs

> /dev/sdb vfat

The ubuntu partition seems to be alive USB. the other is windows.
So it seems there is no recognized Linux partition. `blkid` should show something similar to:

> /dev/sda1: UUID="21a52xxxx" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="643dxxx

My fix would work on a recognized ext4 partition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I wasn't sure about how to post new images so I edited my intial post.

Comment: /dev/sda ntfs is a storage sdd called "Data", /dev/sdb is indeed the usb key I booted from. What do you mean with "your USB stick is not working right"?  I created it with Rufus and an official ubutun 20.04 ISO. Isn't that what you meant in your initial answer: "Start your laptop with a live usb stick"?

Comment: Sorry, I expected a Ubuntu partition on your harddrive -there is none. (any more?)  Only a ntfs partition and a fat32 (your live usb stick).  A linux partition looks like: `/dev/sda1: UUID="21a52xxxx" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="643dxxx"` . The bootloader does not find any data, therefore it can't load. Check your UEFI if it masks sth..

Comment: I've just went through all the menus and sub-menus in the UEFI, both SDDs are visible, and so are the two boot options "Ubuntu" and "Windows boot manager", as shown in the screenshot in the first update on the initial post. Nothing seems to be masked or deactivated.

Comment: Could be. Your screenshots are very clear about this. As long as Linux can't see these partitions (for whatever reasons), it can't use them